# extending a trace from a subalgebra to the entire von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, banach-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let $\{M_\lambda\}$ be an increasing net of von Neumann sublagebras of $M$, equipped with faithfal normal tracial states $\tau_\lambda$ ($\tau_\lambda=\tau_\gamma$ on $M_\gamma$ when $\lambda >\gamma$). Moreover, $\cup M_\lambda$ is dense in $M$ in the weak operator topology.
Can I say that $M$ can be equipped with a faithful normal tracial state, which coincides with $\tau_\lambda$ on $M_\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Every AFD type III factor satisfies all the conditions you mentioned, where the $M_\lambda$ can be taken to be $M_{n(\lambda)}(\mathbb C)$

Comment: What is the embedding $M_{n(\lambda)}\to M_{n(\mu)}$for $\lambda\leq \mu$?

Comment: If you express them as infinite tensor products of $2\times2$ factors, you can take the embedding to be $A\longmapsto \begin{bmatrix} A&0\\0&A\end{bmatrix}$ for one level up, and to obvious generalization for longer jumps.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for answering. However, I may be confused because the tensor product of all $M_{n(\lambda)}$ is a $II_1$-factor. See [Blackadar, 2006, III.3.1.5.]. So, could you expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: That would be infinite dimensional, and it requires you to take a completion by choosing a topology in a certain way; that's not what I'm talking about. The Powers' Factors are even [mentioned in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Tensor_products_of_von_Neumann_algebras), if not entirely correctly. I'll search for a source when I have time. In any case, to answer your question it is enough to know that AFD type III factors exist, it's not about the concrete implemention.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin!

Comment: No problem. My apologies that I don't seem to recall a good source for this stuff. Ideally you want to find a careful construction of the Powers' Factors. But without that, you can look at Theorem 12.3.14 in Kadison-Ringrose, and also A.17 in Stratila's *Modular Theory*.  I'll post again if I happen to recall a better source.